# Finding duplicate words in Lyx

Tags: lyx

Is there any way to run a search which finds all duplicate words within a LyX document? For example, `the the` should be detected.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression (found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg186241.html)) works well when used in 'Advanced Find':

```
[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]\1[[:space:]]
```

Comment: Good find. It is also in the User Guide. See Help > User Guide. There is a whole section on Advanced Find and this is one of the examples.